# Phrase Search in Apache Solr

Tags: apache, search, solr

How could Solr accomplish an end-user behavior like a phrase search?

Let’s say an end-user decides to use quotation marks in their keywords to provide specificity in their search results.

Current:

If you were to query: `your future`, then 10 results would return and print to the page.

Expected:

If you were to query: `“your future”`, then less than 10 results would return and print to the page.

Can the algorithm be updated in the Solr admin panel or is it performed somewhere else?

Comment: Could you illustrate with a better example? what should match and what shouldn't?

Comment: The best way to explain it is that currently I get a set of results from querying, your future. I'd like to query, "your future" and only get an exact match to return. I'm highlighting the quotation marks as an important part of the query. In essence, this would yield precisely one result vs. doing a general search. Can that be accomplished with Solr?

Comment: Could you please share your `schema.xml` for the fields that you are searching on?

Comment: Here you go sir, http://pastebin.com/aswc9Xy4